# Multiple Xcode workspace matches were found. The first match will be used in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, azure-devops, yaml

I'm trying to integrate the Azure CI CD pipeline for Fluter application. I'm getting below mentioned errors in my Azure CI iOS integration and unable to generate signed builds.

Azure Pipeline YML code sign

```
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: "Code sign ipa for Distribution"
  inputs:
    actions: "build"
    xcWorkspacePath: "**/Runner.xcworkspace"
    scheme: "Runner"
    sdk: "iphoneos"
    configuration: "release"
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: "manual"
    signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
```

Error :

```
2022-04-13T08:36:40.5885050Z ##[section]Starting: Code sign ipa for Distribution
2022-04-13T08:36:40.5898160Z ==============================================================================
2022-04-13T08:36:40.5898480Z Task         : Xcode
2022-04-13T08:36:40.5898860Z Description  : Build, test, or archive an Xcode workspace on macOS. Optionally package an app.
2022-04-13T08:36:40.5899750Z Version      : 5.200.0
2022-04-13T08:36:40.5899960Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-04-13T08:36:40.5900350Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode
2022-04-13T08:36:40.5900750Z ==============================================================================
2022-04-13T08:36:40.9267540Z ##[warning]Multiple Xcode workspace matches were found. The first match will be used: /Users/runner/work/1/s/makeawish_mobile/ios/Runner.xcworkspace
2022-04-13T08:36:40.9291950Z [command]/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
2022-04-13T08:36:42.7698550Z Xcode 13.2.1
2022-04-13T08:36:42.7901000Z Build version 13C100
2022-04-13T08:36:43.0275140Z [command]/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration release -workspace /Users/runner/work/1/s/makeawish_mobile/ios/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner build CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Distribution: XXXXXXXXX Ltd PROVISIONING_PROFILE=1319a551-3a8d-XXXXXXXXX PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER= | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/xcpretty -r junit --no-color
2022-04-13T08:36:49.1496410Z --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
2022-04-13T08:36:49.1601060Z { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
2022-04-13T08:36:49.1704150Z { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
2022-04-13T08:36:54.2881640Z ** BUILD FAILED **
2022-04-13T08:36:54.2884770Z 
2022-04-13T08:36:54.3515950Z ##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
2022-04-13T08:36:54.4265010Z ##[section]Finishing: Code sign ipa for Distribution
```

Comment: Could you find the solution?